# How can resume logstash pipeline after terminated or crashed?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, elastic-stack

I designed a pipeline with **elasticsearch** as a input plugin and **s3** as a output plugin. In my case, pipeline started successfully and push the data on s3 bucket but in case of **termination or crash** it does not start where pipeline ended last time. What is happening? let suppose pipeline has been started and data size was **8GB** and pipeline has been pushed data around **6GB on S3 bucket** then suddenly pipeline terminated with any reason and restart pipeline again then data start from first position, 6GB is already there now again same data come then make duplicity on s3 bucket. Any way to resume pipeline? Pipeline already pushed data around 6GB and when we start again after crash it should push data remaining 2GB.

Comment: Are you using in-memory or persistent queues?

Comment: I am using persistent queue.

Comment: From [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) I found 2 cases that might causes your issue: (1) share the sincedb (2) sincedb expired